# CPAN GD 2.71 install failure on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, gd, cpan

I've hit a brick wall here trying to get CPAN GD module running on Cygwin.  It was fine on my old laptop running Win 7, no go on my new laptop running Win 10.  I've fixed a few problems but now I am stumped.

I tried doing a force install; I could get a script to run but then it failed trying to generate a PNG file.

Attempted to install with `cpanm GD` (and other ways too, but that was most recent).  Below is the build.log file from cpanm. The error that looks most suspicious to me is `Can't locate object method "newFromJpeg" via package "GD::Image" at t/transp.t line 24.`, but I haven't a clue *why* it can't locate that method.

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7044 on perl 5.026003 built for x86_64-cygwin-threads-multi
Work directory is /home/neilw/.cpanm/work/1581700101.2031
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have /usr/bin/wget
You have /usr/bin/tar: tar (GNU tar) 1.29
Packaged by Cygwin (1.29-1)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
Searching GD () on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on GD
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/R/RU/RURBAN/GD-2.71.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking GD-2.71.tar.gz
Entering GD-2.71
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::Constant 0.22 ... Yes (0.23)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::PkgConfig 0 ... Yes (1.16)
Configuring GD-2.71
Running Makefile.PL
Notice: Type perl Makefile.PL -h for command-line option summary.

gdlib-config: warning: this script is deprecated; please use the pkg-config file instead.
Configuring for libgd version 2.2.5.
Checking for stray libgd header files...none found.

Included Features:          GD_GIF GD_GIFANIM GD_OPENPOLYGON GD_UNCLOSEDPOLY GD_ANIMGIF GD_FTCIRCLE VERSION_33
GD library used from:       /usr/local
gdlib-config used:          gdlib-config
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Unrecognized argument in LIBS ignored: 'libdir:'
Unrecognized argument in LIBS ignored: '/usr/local/lib'
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for GD
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.24)
Checking if you have Math::Trig 0 ... Yes (1.23)
Checking if you have Test::Fork 0.02 ... Yes (0.02)
Checking if you have Test::More 0.88 ... Yes (1.302073)
Building and testing GD-2.71
"/usr/bin/perl.exe" lib/GD/Image_pm.PL lib/GD/Image.pm
Extracting Image.pm (with variable substitutions)
cp lib/GD/Polygon.pm blib/lib/GD/Polygon.pm
cp lib/GD/Polyline.pm blib/lib/GD/Polyline.pm
cp lib/GD/Simple.pm blib/lib/GD/Simple.pm
cp lib/GD/Group.pm blib/lib/GD/Group.pm
cp lib/GD/Image.pm blib/lib/GD/Image.pm
cp lib/GD.pm blib/lib/GD.pm
AutoSplitting blib/lib/GD.pm (blib/lib/auto/GD)
Running Mkbootstrap for GD ()
chmod 644 "GD.bs"
"/usr/bin/perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- GD.bs blib/arch/auto/GD/GD.bs 644
"/usr/bin/perl.exe" "/usr/share/perl5/5.26/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/usr/share/perl5/5.26/ExtUtils/typemap' -typemap '/home/neilw/.cpanm/work/1581700101.2031/GD-2.71/typemap'  GD.xs > GD.xsc
mv GD.xsc GD.c
gcc -c  -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -D_GNU_SOURCE -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/share/cygpkgs/perl/perl.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/perl-5.26.3-2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/share/cygpkgs/perl/perl.x86_64/src/perl-5.26.3=/usr/src/debug/perl-5.26.3-2 -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wextra -Wformat=1 -DUSEIMPORTLIB -O3   -DVERSION=\"2.71\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.71\"  "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads/CORE"  -DHAVE_FT -DHAVE_GIF -DHAVE_ANIMGIF -DVERSION_33 -DHAVE_UNCLOSEDPOLY -DHAVE_FTCIRCLE -DLIBGD_VERSION="2.2.5" GD.c
GD.c: In function ‘XS_GD__Image_newFromXpm’:
GD.c:1244:9: warning: unused variable ‘filename’ [-Wunused-variable]
  char * filename = (char *)SvPV_nolen(ST(1))
         ^~~~~~~~
GD.c: In function ‘XS_GD__Image_useFontConfig’:
GD.c:4753:6: warning: unused variable ‘flag’ [-Wunused-variable]
  int flag = (int)SvIV(ST(1))
      ^~~~
rm -f blib/arch/auto/GD/GD.dll
g++  --shared  -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -fstack-protector-strong GD.o  -o blib/arch/auto/GD/GD.dll  \
  /usr/lib/perl5/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads/CORE/cygperl5_26.dll -L/usr/local/lib -lgd   \

chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/GD/GD.dll
"/usr/bin/perl.exe" "-Iblib/arch" "-Iblib/lib" bdf_scripts/bdf2gdfont_pl.PL bdf_scripts/bdf2gdfont.pl
Extracting bdf2gdfont.pl (with variable substitutions)
cp bdf_scripts/bdf2gdfont.pl blib/script/bdf2gdfont.pl
"/usr/bin/perl.exe" -MExtUtils::MY -e 'MY->fixin(shift)' -- blib/script/bdf2gdfont.pl
Manifying 1 pod document
Manifying 6 pod documents
"/usr/bin/perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- GD.bs blib/arch/auto/GD/GD.bs 644
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/fork.t .................. ok
# Testing gd 2.2.5 using gd2 support.
# ignore corrupt png error messages...
t/GD.t .................... ok
t/HSV.t ................... ok
t/Polyline.t .............. ok
Can't locate object method "newFromJpeg" via package "GD::Image" at t/transp.t line 24.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 4.
t/transp.t ................ 
Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 8/12 subtests 
t/z_kwalitee.t ............ skipped: No RELEASE_TESTING
t/z_manifest.t ............ skipped: requires a git checkout and a unix for git and diff
t/z_pod-spell-mistakes.t .. skipped: No RELEASE_TESTING
t/z_pod.t ................. skipped: No RELEASE_TESTING

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/transp.t              (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 4 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 12 tests but ran 4.
Files=9, Tests=39,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.06 sys +  0.62 cusr  1.17 csys =  1.88 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/9 test programs. 0/39 subtests failed.
make: *** [Makefile:1151: test_dynamic] Error 255
gcc -c  -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -D_GNU_SOURCE -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/share/cygpkgs/perl/perl.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/perl-5.26.3-2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/share/cygpkgs/perl/perl.x86_64/src/perl-5.26.3=/usr/src/debug/perl-5.26.3-2 -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wextra -Wformat=1 -DUSEIMPORTLIB -O3   -DVERSION=\"2.71\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.71\"  "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads/CORE"  -DHAVE_FT -DHAVE_GIF -DHAVE_ANIMGIF -DVERSION_33 -DHAVE_UNCLOSEDPOLY -DHAVE_FTCIRCLE -DLIBGD_VERSION="2.2.5" GD.c
GD.c: In function ‘XS_GD__Image_newFromXpm’:
GD.c:1244:9: warning: unused variable ‘filename’ [-Wunused-variable]
  char * filename = (char *)SvPV_nolen(ST(1))
         ^~~~~~~~
GD.c: In function ‘XS_GD__Image_useFontConfig’:
GD.c:4753:6: warning: unused variable ‘flag’ [-Wunused-variable]
  int flag = (int)SvIV(ST(1))
      ^~~~
rm -f blib/arch/auto/GD/GD.dll
                                                    -> FAIL Installing GD failed. See /home/neilw/.cpanm/work/1581700101.2031/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

Comment: the two steps `cpan App::cpanminus` and ` `/home/Marco/perl5/bin/cpanm GD::Image` works for me on latest Cygwin x86_64. What was your command ?

Comment: I initially did `cpanm GD`, which failed as above.  I just uninstalled it (remember I force-installed but it didn't work properly) and tried `cpanm GD::Image` and got the same failure as before.  I'm frustrated that I don't even know where to begin to figure this out, given the errors I'm getting.

Comment: any reason to not use the `perl-GD` package ? https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/perl-GD.html

Comment: I was unaware of perl-GD, will give it a look in the morning.  Unclear how it relates to the GD CPAN module.  API looks the same at a quick glance...

Comment: @matzeri I tried installing perl-GD through the Cygwin installer and it seems to install into Perl 5.26 while I'm using 5.30, and Cygwin has generally ignored my attempts to use 5.26 instead of 5.30 (I've been through multiple complete re-installs of Cygwin now).  I've also been unable to successfully move the 5.26 GD into 5.30; dunno if that would even have a chance of working anyway.

Comment: not your fault. Perl was updated to 5.30 but perl-GD was not aligned due to absence of the maintainer : https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2020-02/msg00005.html give distribution some time to solve the problem

Comment: Ah, thanks. In the meantime I have been able to get GD working with Strawberry Perl, but I'm still hoping to solve the problem asked here.

Comment: https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin-announce/2020-March/009443.html